# How can I lock parts of the code in an inter-request manner?

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, web, locking

Consider a PHP script (possibly calling functions in other scripts). I want to make sure some part of it can only be executed by one request at a time. For example:

```
doSomething();
doSomethingElse(); // Lock this: Can only be executed by one request at a time
yetAnotherThing();
```

So if request A is currently 'inside' `doSomethingElse()`, I want any farther requests to be queued before the line of code calling this function.

I haven't found a solution to this online, because I'm talking about a lock between requests, and not a lock for separate threads executing as part of the same request. I am using Apache server.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to guard the execution by setting up a flag to indicate what should happen or not happen.

You can store the guard-status in any other storage, which is persistent across requests: database, session, flat-file...

The most basic thing you could do is to write a flag file.
This will exclude all subsequent requests from processing `doSomethingElse()`, while the file exists. But, when the file is gone, the next request will exec `doSomethingElse()` again.

---

You might use `flock()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)
or your own flat-file locking approach. Just for the concept:

Add `file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/doSomethingElse.processing.flag', 'processing');`

at the start of the `doSomethingElse()` and remove it at the end of the function.

Then wrap the execution into a condition check:

```
doSomething();
if( ! is_file(__DIR__.'/doSomethingElse.processing.flag')) {
    doSomethingElse(); 
}
yetAnotherThing();
```

---

**Building a Queue**

Well, you could expand the given idea or use a prepared library/tool for the job.

For building a "queue" you would need to expand the lock-idea and:

- add a processing ID,
- add a stack to lookup the current lowest ID for processing,
- and the lookup and processing logic itself

  - including "locking" for the resource processed

A queue locks the resource to process and only allows the lowest ID.
The lock is often called semaphore. (It could actually be the highest ID, that depends on your processing logic - its basically LIFO or FIFO stack processing.)

Create a queue and put the job in, then add a worker running as a cronjob or daemon. The worker takes jobs off the queue, processes it and returns the result with the status flag "done". You might then periodically poll the queue to see if job have finished. You can use a database for the queue, pick one that supports locking.

```
while(1) {
  begin new transaction;
  remove item from queue;
  process item;
  save new state of item;
  commit;
}
```

Not sure where you are heading, but you have a lot of options to implement it:

- For a file based queue-ing mechanism see this basic tutorial: http://squirrelshaterobots.com/programming/php/building-a-queue-server-in-php-part-1-understanding-the-project/
- You could rely on [SPLQueue](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splqueue.php) and combine it with the locking idea.
- PHP has support for semaphores, too: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php
- Then there are real job-queue systems like Gearman, Beanstalk, Redis or any message queue, like RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ.

  - See the gearman examples http://php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse.php
- http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this makes any farther requests 'skip' the 'locked' part, while I want them to be 'queued' before it. Do you know a way to acheive this? Or is there a way to expand on your proposed solution to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put doSomethingElse() function in another file and then you can use

> `flock`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php
This function is to prevent simultaneous access.